# Should a temporary (non-member) variable be used if not strictly necessary?

Tags: python, performance, memory

If I'm defining a class, and I need to instantiate some objects, but these objects don't need to be attributes, and have no further references in the class, should they just be instantiated anonymously, or under a temporary variable?
For instance, I'm making a GUI program in python, and certain buttons and labels only need to be made and placed, but require no further action beyond that. So of the two, would either of these be preferred?

```
class Foo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        pass

    def bar(self):
        tk.Label(self, text="This is a label.")
```

```
class Foo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        pass

    def bar(self):
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is a label.")
```

On one hand, I could see how making a variable could increase code readability. On the other hand, I'm not sure if the variable would introduce more memory usage, or slow down the program. It might also be that the compiler optimises the memory usage anyway, so it doesn't really matter.
Any more information on this would be appreciated.

Comment: "I'm not sure if the variable would introduce more memory usage, or slow down the program." it wont.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always a good idea to make the code more readable and also this wont effect any performance. And also as a practice you should be able to make your code both forward and backward compatible, so if you have the reference to the `tk.Label(self, text="This is a label.")` then if you have any changes in future to this label object or add any additional capability i believe you can do it more efficiently since you already have the reference to it.